# Initialising texture of MTLPixelFormatR32Float in metal

Tags: ios, metal

I have a buffer initialised with a single-channel floating point image, which I need to get into a floating point format texture (MTLPixelFormatR32Float). I've tried creating the texture with that format and doing the following:

```
float *rawData = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * img.cols * img.rows);

for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++){
     rawData[i * img.cols + j] = img.at<float>(i, j);
     }
 }

MTLTextureDescriptor *textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR32Float
                                                                                                 width:img.cols
                                                                                                height:img.rows
                                                                                             mipmapped:NO];

[texture replaceRegion:region mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:&rawData bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow];
```

where `rawData` is my buffer with the necessary floating point data. This doesn't work, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the `[texture replaceRegion...]` line. I've also tried the MTKTextureLoader, which also returns nil instead of the texture.

Help would be appreciated. I would be most grateful if anyone has a working method of how to initialise the MTLPixelFormatR32Float texture with custom floating point data for data-parallel computation purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes that you pass to replaceRegion should point to your data. You are incorrectly passing a pointer to a pointer.
To fix it, replace `withBytes:&rawData` with `withBytes:rawData`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. I tried this, and while I did not encounter an error, the texture was not initialised with the data either. I am now trying to forgo this process, and writing a kernel to initialise the R32Float texture with a buffer.

Comment: If you show your code for `bytesPerRow` and `region`, I may be able to spot additional problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to fix the other error, which was occurring due to my wrong initialisation of data buffers.